# while animating in pygame image become twice the pixel size and glitching while displaying single image its ok

Tags: python, loops, animation, pygame

I try to animate but displaying single image is good but animating more image mage double the size of image and glitching!

```
import pygame,sys

class dog(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list=[]
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mm.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mn.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mm.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mm.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mn.png"))

        self.count = 0
        self.image =self.list[self.count]
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(32,32))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))
    def update(self):
        self.count +=1
        if self.count >= len(self.list):
            self.count=0
        self.image =self.list[self.count]
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
windows =pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

tiles =pygame.sprite.Group()
dog1 =dog()
tiles.add(dog1)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    windows.fill((255,255,255))
    tiles.draw(windows)
    tiles.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

while animating in pygame image become twice the pixel size and glitching while displaying single image its ok

I tried make animation but image are become flippering and size become double I not able to find what error pls give me solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to scale all the images in the list:

```py
class dog(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list=[]
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mm.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mn.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mm.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mm.png"))
        self.list.append(pygame.image.load("sword of stones\mn.png"))

        # v INSERT v
        self.list = [pygame.transform.scale(img, (32,32)) for img in self.list]

        self.count = 0
        self.image = self.list[self.count]

        # v DELETE v
        # self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(32,32))                   
        
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))
```